# Javascript variable into href="mailto:" string

Tags: javascript, html, email

I am trying to create a simple page that can take some user inputs and print them back out, and I have found a way that is working fine. But there is one thing I can not manage to do, and that is to take the E-post input from the user and add it into the "mailto" string so that when the entered mail is clicked it will open in the users e-mail program with the entered mail preentered.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML JavaScript output on same page</title>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function showMessage(){
        var navn = document.getElementById("navn").value;
        display_navn.innerHTML= navn;

        var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
        display_mail.innerHTML= mail;

        var tlf = document.getElementById("tlf").value;
        display_tlf.innerHTML= tlf;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Navn: <br>
<input type="text" id = "navn"><br>
E-post: <br>
<input type="text" id = "mail"><br>
Mobil: <br>
<input type="text" id = "tlf"><br>

<br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
</form>

<br>
<br>

<span id = "display_navn"></span><br>
<br>
<a href="mailto:" + mail><span id = "display_mail"></a></span><br>
<br>
<span id = "display_tlf"></span>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is a screenshot of what it looks like.

[image]

And I want to make it so that when I click on TestEmail the e-mail client I have opens, and the adress is entered already. Is this something that can be done? 
If it would be hard to do it on the same site, I could consider having the inputs on a single site, and then open a new site with the generated content when clicking on the submit button if that would be easyer.

Comment: `myanchor.href = 'mailto:' + navn + mail + tlf` - you'll have to format the message properly though

Comment: Seriously? @Zaka?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki No buddy. Not at all. That's something that takes from the query string and this is totally different mate. Both the solution and the question doesn't have any similarities. Check my answer, and check the answer provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need this extra line of code:

```
display_mail.parentNode.setAttribute("href", "mailto:" + mail);
```

And don't forget to close the `</form>` tag.

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/revahabowe**

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks! Could you give a quick explaination how it worked?

Comment: @Siesta You need to set the `href` attribute. You didn't do that at all. And JavaScript is not there when you use that inside HTML tag. It was invalid.